# javascript canvas animation effect

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Im currently trying to figure out how to change the radious of arcs in canvas in every row and then back.
lets say i have have arcs like this

```
 * * * *
 * * * *
 * * * *
```

what i want to do is do animation which will do as following

```
* * * *       * * * *     * * * *    * * * *   o o o o   * * * * 
* * * *       * * * *     * * * *    o o o o   * * * *   * * * *
* * * *       * * * *     o o o o    * * * *   * * * *   * * * *
* * * *       o o o o     * * * *    * * * *   * * * *   * * * *
```

so far i  have just drawn arcs on the canvas using

```
      var canvas = document.getElementsByTagName("canvas")[0];
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
canvas.width = 280;
canvas.height = 100;
var x = 18;
var y = 15;
var rows_x=1;
var rows_y=9;
for (var i = 1; i < 37; i++) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(x, y, 5, 0, 2 * Math.PI);

    ctx.stroke();
    x += 30;
    if (i % 9 === 0) {
        x = 18;
        y += 25;
    }
}
x = 18;
y = 15;

function large() {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 280, 100);
    for (var i = 1; i < 37; i++) {
        ctx.beginPath();
        if (i >rows_x&& i <= 9) {
            ctx.arc(x, y, 10, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
            ctx.fillStyle = 'green';
            ctx.fill();
           rows_x += 9;
            rows_y += 10;

        }
     else {
        ctx.arc(x, y, 5, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
        ctx.stroke();

    }
    x += 30;
    if (i % 9 == 0) {
        x = 18;
        y += 25
    }
}}


setInterval(large,1000)
```

this my code has some glitch but thats not important. the change between the size of arcs is instant which mean it isnt animated or atleast doesnt look like that, how can i achieve the animation effect in this case?

Comment: You can use svg for CSS transition and animation features. If you want to stick with canvas, you have to animate all frames by calling intervals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can perform your animation by using **setTimout()** function and **recursive** call.

**EDIT**

To perform some animation transition, you can use the [**window.requestAnimationFrame()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) method, which is a useful method to update animation before next repaint.

So, i have made a generic code which can handle any number of line.

```
      //Retrieve context
  var context = document.querySelector('#canvas').getContext('2d');

  var count = 0;
  var toRadius = 0;
  var line_drawn = 0;
  //Enter a number of line
  var number_line = 5;

  //Init function to buil our grid
  function init(a){
    var x = 10;
    var y = 10;
    //Calculate size of the grid
    var size = Math.pow(number_line,2);
    //Build our grid 4x4
    for (var i = 0; i < size; ++i){
      context.beginPath();
      context.arc(x, y, 5, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
      context.stroke();
      x += 30;
      ++count;
      count === number_line
      ? (count = 0, y += 25, x = 10)
      : y;
    }
    //Call our draw function, start to fill bottom lane
    draw(10, 10 + 25 * a)
  }


  function change(iterator){
    setTimeout(function(){
      //Reset our canvas
      context.clearRect(0,0,600,600);
      //Calculate the index of the new line that must be filled
      var index = number_line - 1 - iterator;
      //Re-build our grid and fill the new line
      init(index);
    }, 500);
  }

  function circle(x, y, radius){
    context.arc(x, y, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    context.fillStyle = 'green';
    context.fill();
    radius++;
    if (radius < 11){
      window.requestAnimationFrame(function(){
        circle(x, y, radius);
      });
    }
  }


  function draw(x, y) {
    context.beginPath();
    //Use requestAnimationFrame
    window.requestAnimationFrame(function(){
      circle(x, y, toRadius);
    });
    ++count;
    //If we haven't draw all the line
    if (count < number_line) {
      //draw the next circle
      draw(x+30, y);
    } else {
      count = 0;
      ++line_drawn;
      line_drawn < number_line + 1
      ? change(line_drawn)
      : ( line_drawn = 0, change(line_drawn) );
    }
  }

  //Start to build the grid
  init(number_line - 1);
```

And in your HTML :

```
<canvas id="canvas" width="600px" height="600px"></canvas>
```

You can see here the [**Working Plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/NrtYlXHCixkW33yMEzJw?p=preview)

Comment: thanks , seems like you fixed my glitch. but as animation , i meant the animation of changing size of arc from "  * " to " o ". Transation-like animation ( like css)

Comment: @trolkura : If you want to perform animation, you should use the `requestAnimationFrame()` method. I have update my code and the plunker.

Comment: thanks! , is there any way how to animate change from "O" to " * " ? thats the main source of my struggle